# SQL Server complains about an invalid geometry - sometimes

Tags: sql-server

I am experience very strange behavior from SQL Server (version 15.0.2000.5), trying to intersect shapes. I have an SQL query that fails claiming the geometry is invalid. The SQL looks like this:

```
DECLARE @area1 varchar(8000)='MULTIPOLYGON (((215072.25960000046 756832.8172999993, 215620.12090000045 756851.07729999907, 218063.69529999979 756932.5296, 221895.83930000011 757638.45670000091, 225627.12870000023 757840.15839999914, 230568.58710000012 758445.24689999968, 233997.36039999966 758747.7873, 236619.3518000003 758848.64200000092, 239543.89960000012 758546.1018000003, 242972.68090000004 758041.89240000024, 244989.61600000039 757840.19089999981, 244888.76929999981 759957.96440000087, 243476.8984000003 762176.56069999933, 242165.89890000038 763991.79399999976, 240955.72979999986 765302.78559999913, 239140.48819999956 767723.0833, 239140.48819999956 768933.2444000002, 240249.7944 770244.24400000088, 242266.72130000032 771151.8487, 245897.20440000016 772765.4048999995, 249124.29239999969 774782.32359999977, 250838.68709999975 778311.9355999995, 251544.61440000031 780429.70930000022, 252452.22709999979 783253.39399999939, 254570.00090000033 790615.15839999914, 256158.53780000005 795662.52910000086, 254726.16199999955 797001.34400000051, 254888.59640000015 797513.25290000066, 254898.44359999988 798625.66310000047, 253258.98489999957 799451.17530000024, 252855.71129999962 798709.3200000003, 252973.84530000016 797655.99290000089, 252634.20999999996 797075.17779999971, 252190.76159999985 796008.04839999974, 251317.53710000031 795453.58180000074, 251370.26620000042 793689.42420000024, 250427.13069999963 793138.4020000007, 250427.1387 790307.3662, 250916.62999999989 789209.34180000052, 249474.64219999965 782700.58070000075, 250083.19979999959 781986.20020000078, 248866.1091 780226.72709999979, 247305.04710000008 780094.42600000091, 247344.73579999991 777236.92039999925, 245929.2098000003 777501.5064000003, 244235.86290000007 777620.55619999953, 242000.11730000004 777329.51669999957, 240611.05310000014 774591.07709999941, 237330.1986999996 774075.13199999928, 236060.20069999993 774048.67019999959, 235623.62490000017 773360.7435999997, 233956.75600000005 773453.35579999909, 232789.69579999987 773886.77889999934, 231496.12110000011 775689.07709999941, 230292.25760000013 776945.84019999951, 230715.5820000004 777898.34490000084, 230040.89020000026 778784.69889999926, 228559.23819999956 778401.03869999945, 227884.5382000003 779141.88089999929, 227064.33469999954 778877.28690000065, 226654.22890000045 778440.72729999945, 225820.78239999991 778414.26559999958, 222341.52489999961 777461.76090000011, 221534.53199999966 778149.67960000038, 220304.22269999981 778440.71110000089, 219778.0251000002 777706.78219999932, 219778.0251000002 777303.40330000035, 218505.06089999992 776720.91870000027, 216930.78000000026 777607.26469999924, 214840.57870000042 776800.27979999967, 215038.27639999986 777303.39509999938, 214867.03220000025 777461.73670000024, 210064.83690000046 777726.30639999919, 211912.05159999989 775992.38729999959, 212315.43039999995 775639.42779999971, 213525.59130000044 774580.54910000041, 214123.19930000044 773833.54710000008, 214534.05090000015 772765.33180000074, 214634.89759999979 770849.25159999914, 214231.52670000028 767622.18799999915, 214735.7686999999 764294.27759999968, 215643.38129999954 762075.66530000046, 215744.22800000012 760462.12529999949, 215380.29470000044 760220.97819999978, 214433.23639999982 759352.8191, 214130.69620000012 758243.50489999913, 215071.48959999997 756833.9682, 215072.25960000046 756832.8172999993)), ((215038.31689999998 756831.66640000045, 215139.17179999966 756730.8359999992, 215108.80360000022 756778.05399999954, 215072.25960000046 756832.8172999993, 215038.31689999998 756831.66640000045)))'

SELECT DISTINCT E.entity_id AS entity_id, E.origin_table AS origin_table, E.origin_id AS origin_id
FROM entities E
JOIN entity_shapes ES ON (E.entity_id=ES.entity_id)
JOIN entity_thesaurus ETH_0 ON (E.entity_id=ETH_0.entity_id)
WHERE
ES.shape.STIntersects(geometry::STGeomFromText(@area1, 2039)) = 1
AND (453=ETH_0.WID)
```

*However*, when I remove the join the `entity_thesaurus` table, the query works:

```
SELECT DISTINCT E.entity_id AS entity_id, E.origin_table AS origin_table, E.origin_id AS origin_id
FROM entities E
JOIN entity_shapes ES ON (E.entity_id=ES.entity_id)
WHERE ES.shape.STIntersects(geometry::STGeomFromText(@area1, 2039)) = 1
```

In both cases `@area1` is exactly the same - it's literally the same `DECLARE` line, not even copy pasted. The `entity_thesaurus` table contains three fields, all integers - no geometry fields are all.

The exact error is as follows:

> Msg 6522, Level 16, State 1, Line 11
>
> A .NET Framework error occurred during execution of user-defined routine or aggregate "geometry":
>
> System.ArgumentException: 24144: This operation cannot be completed because the instance is not valid. Use MakeValid to convert the instance to a valid instance. Note that MakeValid may cause the points of a geometry instance to shift slightly.
>
> System.ArgumentException:

Again, it only appears when running the first query, removing the join to `entity_thesaurus` eliminates the error and the query works.

Comment: The problem is not the variable, it's that you have a entity_shapes row with invalid geometry. Think of a bomb defusing scene in an old Stallone movie. You have to cut the wires in correct order. SQL Server tries to evaluate the join. Maybe it cuts `(E.entity_id=ES.entity_id)`first, maybe `ES.shape.STIntersects(geometry::STGeomFromText(@area1, 2039)) = 1`. When it guesses wrong: boom. Run: `select * from entity_shapes where shape.STIsValid() = 0` and see where the bomb is

Comment: This is super weird, as I the query works well when I intersect on ALL records in entity_shapes - valid or invalid. I will try to look for invalid polygons and remove them.